# how to pass environment values with default values to entrypoint in docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker container that I would like to start with a specific entrypoint script.

the issue is that my entrypoint script require some environment variables that I would like to set default values for.

```
    entrypoint:
  - /bin/bash
  - -c
  - |
    set -e
    java -jar liquibase.jar --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
    --classpath=mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar \
    --url="jdbc:mysql://${DB_HOST}/${DB_NAME}" --username=${DB_USER} --password=${DB_PASSWORD} \
    --logLevel=warning migrate;
```

my specific case is that I would like to connect to a DB and most of the times the db parameters exist with default values (like:

`environment:
      DB_USER: ${DB_USER:-root}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD:-123}
      DB_HOST: ${DB_HOST:-mysql}`
      DB_NAME: ${DB_NAME:-myDb}
)

when I execute it I get the following error (one for each config):

```
WARNING: The DB_HOST variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

do you know if why the default values not passed into the container (when adding an .env file with the specific parameter everything works great and the values available in the entrypoint execution)?

why the default value is not set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that the following workaround works:
extract the entrypoint script into a .sh script file.

when you will start your container the environment variables will get the default values in case that it is not configured in the .env file.

the new script can use the parameters directly and the values exist.

I'm not sure why this is the behavior but it is probably something in the loading order of each section of the docker-compose.